# Can a multi-character constant in Fortran be declared without any length specification?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I've been told in an introductory course on programming that a
character constant in Fortran95 can be declared without any length
specification, e.g.:

```
character, parameter :: STR = 'Hello World!'
```

The same statement can be found in Stephen J. Chapman's book “Fortran
95/2003 for Scientists and Engineers” (p. 34), which says

> If the named constant is of type CHARACTER, then it is not necessary
>   to declare the length of the character string. Since the named
>   constant is being defined on the same line as its type declaration,
>   the Fortran compiler can directly count the number of characters in
>   the string. For example, the following statements declare a named
>   constant error_message to be the 14-character string ‘Unknown
>   error!’.
>
> ```
> CHARACTER, PARAMETER :: ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Unknown error!'
> ```

I know that it is possible to use `(len=*)`.  But is it actually
possible to omit the length selector entirely?

When I tested it with the GFortran and Intel compilers, the value was
always truncated to the first character.  Is there another compiler
that supports this?  Or can someone point me to a part of the Fortran
standard which clarifies this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Fortran 2008 Standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), the `character` has a length of one, if no length is specified. This is given in Cl. 4.4.3.2 "Character type specifier":

> 4 [...] If the length is not specified in a
>   char-selector or a * char-length, the length is 1.

This is independent of whether it is a character variable or named constant. This actually happens in your code.

The same line is present in the [Fortran 95 Standard](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/standing/archive/007/97-007r2/pdf/97-007r2.pdf) and in the [Fortran 90 Standard](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N001-N1100/N692.pdf), Cl. 5.1.1.5 in both documents.

I guess Chapman takes his information from the [FORTRAN 77 Standard](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf-4.html#sh-4.8), Cl. 4.8.1 Character Constant, although this clause does not refer to named constants:

> The length of a character constant is the number of characters between
>   the delimiting apostrophes, except that each pair of consecutive
>   apostrophes counts as a single character. The delimiting apostrophes
>   are not counted. The length of a character constant must be greater
>   than zero.

Apart from that, I could not find any reference in any Standard or compiler documentation to support Chapman's statement.

Answer (score 1):

The Fortran 2008 standard (I'm referencing the last freely available draft ahead of the official standard) says in section 4.4.3.2, paragraph 4 (emphasis is mine):

> The char-selector in a CHARACTER intrinsic-type-spec and the * char-length in an entity-decl or in a component-
>   decl of a type definition specify character length. The * char-length in an entity-decl or a component-decl specifies
>   an individual length and overrides the length specified in the char-selector , if any. If a * char-length is not specified
>   in an entity-decl or a component-decl , the length-selector or type-param-value specified in the char-selector is the
>   character length. **If the length is not specified in a char-selector or a * char-length, the length is 1**.

This says that if you do not specify a length via `*len` or `(LEN=len)` then the character length is `1`.  The standard does not make any exception (that I can find) for character types with the parameter attribute (5.3.13).

It is possible the author possessed a compiler implementing his claim as a vendor extension but I cannot find basis for it in the standard.  I tested with gfortran 5.1.0, ifort 14.0.1 and pgf90 11.9 and all conform to the standard.